# Disabled checkbox to be true on selecting a record

Tags: visualforce, pageblocktable, checkbox

I'm having a requirement to highlight the `apex:column` in `apex:pageblocktable` when a particular record is selected.

So I kept a checkbox which is disabled and when I select a record, the disabled field should become true. How can I achieve this?

Here is the code:

```
  <apex:pageblockTable value="{!accList}" var="acc"  >
        <apex:column headerValue="Action"  ><apex:inputCheckbox value="{!acc.Check_Box__c}" disabled="true" style="color:grey;backgroundcolor:grey;" /></apex:column>
<apex:column headervalue="Group #"  ><apex:commandlink value="{!acc.AccountNumber}" action="{!ViewAccRecord}" rerender="thetable"><apex:param id="AccId" name="AccViewId" assignto="{!AccRecId}"  value="{!acc.id}"/></apex:commandlink></apex:column>
    </apex:pageblockTable>
```

Comment: You should add JavaScript or Jquery code to highlight the row. How does disabling a button helps here? how can you select a record if its disabled?

Comment: What do you mean by "select a record"? Your checkbox is initially disabled, so there must be something else to select a record.

Comment: I just want to let the user know that the record is selected by enabling the checkbox to true. Can I do this by javascript.I have disabled the checkbox because I don't want the user to change the value.Anyways highligting the record I have already done it by using the javascript

Comment: yes .A hyperlink is added. I have updated the code

Comment: The hyperlink that you added should take you to the account detail page, not related to your issue. On which event do you know a record is selected and then you will enable the checkbox?

Comment: @SantanuHalder sorry for misleading.edited the code. When I click on the hyperlink the detailed record is displayed in the same page and the user should know which record is selected in the list of records.Hence a checkbox is placed and it should be enabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have this on your outputLink element

```
onclick="jsFunc('{!acc.Id}');return false;"
```

It will pass the account Id of the current row to the jsFunc, the JS function.

Next, on the inputCheckbox put the account id in the styleClass attribute.

```
<apex:inputCheckbox styleClass="{!acc.Id}" disabled="true"
```

Sorry for this 'unethical' usage of `styleClass`. I will keep looking for other ways to do this and will update the answer.

Next, the js function.

```
function jsFunc(accId)
{
    document.getElementsByClassName(accId)[0].disabled = false;
}
```

------------ OR -----------------

You can have a wrapper class for this requirement like this.

```
public AccountWrapper
{
    public Account acc;
    public Boolean isSelected;
}
```

So the pageBlockTable will loop through a list of the AccountWrapper objects with isSelected initialized to false for all.

So your vf will look like this.

```
<apex:pageblockTable id="pgBlkTable" value="{!accWrapList}" var="accWrap"  >
    <apex:column headerValue="Action"  >
    <apex:commandLink ..... reRender="pgBlkTable" >click here</apex:commandlink>
    <apex:inputCheckbox  disabled="{!IF(accWrap.isSelected==false, true, false)}" style="color:grey;backgroundcolor:grey;" />
```

So in your `ViewAccRecord` function you change the `isSelected` value of the selected record to `true`, and the rest will be taken care of by the `reRender` attribute of outputLink.

Comment: or else can I make the checkbox to true when i click on the record and give it to the user as readonly so that they will be not editing the field.Can you please modify your code accordingly

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName(checkbx)[0].checked = true;` have this in your JS function, you should be good to go.